# how to structure query for drilldown of unknown level

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

What I have is a bunch of categories and subcategories stored in Oracle. The relationship is only represented one way: each row has a categoryid and a parentid which is the categoryid of that row's parent if it has one. If no parent, then parentid is 0. That is:

**Tools:** categoryid, 1; parentid, 0

**Materials:** categoryid, 2; parentid, 0

**hammer:** categoryid, 3; parentid, 1

**nails:** categoryid, 4; parentid, 2

**etc.**

In another table, I have items. They each have unique IDs and a related categoryid:

**short nails:** itemid, 1; categoryid, 4

**long nails:** itemid, 2; categoryid, 4

**double-sided:** itemid, 3; categoryid, 3

**rubber:** itemid, 4; categoryid, 3

**etc.**

I'm building a 'browse category' web app with coldfusion. When they select a category, the resulting table should pull all the items from the selected category, plus items in that category's subcategories. That is, if a use selected category tools, no item has a categoryid of 1, but two items have a categoryid of 3 which is a subcategory of tools, therefore those items should be displayed:

**Clicks 'Tools' link >> double-sided and rubber hammer are displayed**

The issue I'm having right now is that there is no way to tell what the extent of the categories will be. The categories list could possibly be hundreds of rows long with a very varied assortments of category/subcategory relationships. Currently, there is a subcategory that is 6 levels deep.

My question is how should I structure my query without endless 'if a category with a parent id of *whatever* then query for items'? This cannot be the only way. Query for categories with parentid of selected categoryid, then query for categories with parentid of those categories that were found in the previous query, then repeat again with new results, then repeat again with new results, each time adding exponentially to the number of queries I would be hand-coding!!

My initial reaction was to do this: Loop an array that was initially populated with the first 'parentid query'. As it looped through, query for the parentid of each of the array's items. If it found anything, add it to the currently looping array. Something like this:

```
<!--- populate Inital 'parentid query' array --->
<cfset newArray = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="i">
    <cfset #ArrayAppend(newArray,i)#>
</cfloop>

<!--- if parentid is found for index, add to newArray --->
<cfloop array="#newArray#" index="i">
    <query for parentid with 'i'>
    <if successful>
        ArrayAppend(newArray,everythingTheQueryFoundWithParentIdOfI)
    </if>
</cfloop>
```

But I found that appending to an array while in a loop is valid code, but doesn't actually increase the iterations of the loop. :/ Same for setting the loop to a integer variable and increasing that instead. Any ideas what I can do? Thanks for reading my long post lol

Comment: Are you allowed to use Oracle's `CONNECT BY` syntax, which does hierarchical querying?

Comment: make sure you pick another index if you're looping inside a loop.  "... doesn't actually increase the iterations of the loop" smells funny.

Comment: so, create an array with initial values of 1-10 (why?) No loop needed. <cfset newArray=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"] >then loop the array running a query for each initial element (not the best idea). If successful (if recordCount?) add the value to the array so now you have an 11 element array with the 11th value being "3"(depending the selected columns of "everythingTheQueryFoundWithParentIdOfI" are) so you expect your loop to now iterate 11 times instead of 10 (for values you're going to look up momentarily anyway)? I think your logic may be flawed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query could use the connect_by syntax:

```
SELECT cat.cat_desc, items.item_desc
  FROM cat JOIN items ON cat.category_id = items.category_id
 START WITH cat.category_id = 1  -- ID of the starting category
 CONNECT BY PRIOR cat.category_id = cat.parent_category_id;
```